# What is the best way to select the first two records of each group by a "SELECT" command?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

For instance I have the following table:

```
id group data
1 1 aaa
2 1 aaa
3 2 aaa
4 2 aaa
5 2 aaa
6 3 aaa
7 3 aaa
8 3 aaa
```

What is the best way to select the first two records of each group by a "SELECT" command?
If there is no good way to do so, what routine do you suggest?(in PHP)

(model outcome)

```
1 1 aaa
2 1 aaa
3 2 aaa
4 2 aaa
6 3 aaa
7 3 aaa
```

I knew that cross-joining by a.id >= b.id in a sub-query can be working but I am looking for a more scalable solution that can be applied on a table with millions of records. Thanks

Comment: What RDBMS you are using? MySQL, SQL Server, ...??

Comment: Your select query with LIMIT 2 at the end, if you want only two records

Comment: preferably MySQL, but I am rather like to know the possible way to do so, so simply use the one you are familiar with.

Comment: @Deepanshu You probably mis-read the question. For that instance, I will need 2 records per group.

Comment: possible duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191398/get-first-last-n-records-per-group-by

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group

Comment: check JW's answer, it will help you :)

Comment: Never use `group` as field name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select a.*
from Tablename a
where 
(
   select count(*) 
   from Tablename as b
   where a.group = b.group and a.id >= b.id
) <= 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b596/3)

Comment: That is one solution suggested from my friend by using `a.id <= b.id` for cross joining, but I foresaw a big performance issue that the indeterminate section of `count(*)` is growing in the index power when the table is growing large. Am I right? I know my expression may be a bit confusing though.

Comment: it is working good, but it not giving the first two records, it is giving last two records, so better check it..

Comment: @Deepanshu it can simply be change into `a.id >= b.id` here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b596/3

Comment: thats great.. actually I just wanted to point that out to Abby

Comment: @JW : Your query don't give what OP want. Check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b596/4 OP want id as 3,4 and not 4,5

Comment: @FahimParkar read what i said on Deepanshu. it can simply be change into `a.id >= b.id` here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b596/3

Answer (score 3):

I like this trick, that makes use of GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function, and FIND_IN_SET:

```
SELECT
  Tablename.*
FROM
  Tablename INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `group`, GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id) ids
    FROM Tablename
    GROUP BY `group`) grp ON
  Tablename.`group` = grp.`group` AND
  FIND_IN_SET(Tablename.id, ids)<=2
ORDER BY
  Tablename.`group`, Tablename.id
```

Performances can't be too good, as it can't make use of an index.

Or you can also use this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.`group`, t1.data
from
  Tablename t1 INNER JOIN Tablename t2
  ON t1.`group` = t2.`group` AND t1.id>=t2.id
GROUP BY
  t1.id, t1.`group`, t1.data
HAVING
  COUNT(*)<=2
ORDER BY
  t1.`group`, t1.id, t1.data
```

Answer (score -1):

You select, filter and order your query like normal and then

for **MSSQL**

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM foo;
```

From what I can remember **Sybase**, **Oracle** and possible a few other **RDBMS's** uses this syntax to.

for **MySQL** you do

```
SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 2;
```

**Update:**

Yes, I misread your question, sorry. Seems like a few of us did :)

Then it depends on whether you **RDBMS** supports **HAVING** or not etc. You could construct a query using **HAVING** or using **IN** and a subquery in the **IN** clause.

For **MSSQL** I think you could do something like (code not tested)

```
SELECT id, data
    FROM (
        SELECT id, data, Rank() over (Partition BY group ORDER BY id DESC ) AS Rank
        FROM table
        ) rs WHERE Rank <= 2)
```

But since this depends on your **RDBMS** I ask you to look at similar questions and see which one works best for your case since **MSSQL** supports some things **MySQL** doesn't and the other way around.

*Here are some examples*

[Select top 10 records for each category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176964/select-top-10-records-for-each-category)

[How to select the last two records for each topic_id in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596489/how-to-select-the-last-two-records-for-each-topic-id-in-mysql)

Comment: You probably mis-read the question. For that instance, I will need 2 records per group.