# Explain the query to select the first two records of each group by a “SELECT” command

Tags: mysql

I have find an answer to my query problem from [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894785/what-is-the-best-way-to-select-the-first-two-records-of-each-group-by-a-select?answertab=oldest#tab-top)
However, I am problem in understanding the logic of the query. Can anyone help me understand this query?

Query:

```
select a.*
from Tablename a
where 
(
   select count(*) 
   from Tablename as b
   where a.group = b.group and a.id >= b.id
) <= 2
```

Comment: It's a correlated subquery. That's all. That said, I doubt you even need a subquery for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql will first form the query op of

```
select count(*) 
   from Tablename as b
   where a.group = b.group and a.id >= b.id
```

this will count the record of table name `Tablename` on condition that `a.group` column value is equal to `b.group` column value and `a.id`'s value greater than `b.id`'s value, it will count the record which satisfy this condition.

then it passes it to main / parent query it's op.
now parent query will count the record from `Tablename` on condition that `subquery`'s op less than or equal to `2`.

And why are you querying on same table (in main + sub query) ?  and where's the `b.group` came from ?

Comment: Basically, I want to get the last two entries of each of the group. I am trying to understand this concept but "a.id >= b.id" is confusing me a little. How this condition is impacting on the results?